# How do I write a function that finds the sum of factorial of even numbers?

Tags: python, factorial

I've got a question- how do I write a function **sum_even_factorials** that finds the sum of the factorials of the even numbers that are less than or equal to n.

Eg:

> > > sum_even_factorials(1)=
> > > 1
> > > sum_even_factorials (3)=
> > > 3
> > > sum_even_factorials (6)=
> > > 747

This is my current code:

[image]

Is there a logical error in the current code?

Comment: you should return somethin if n is neither zero nor even

Comment: please post code as text and not as image ...

Comment: And imagine what happens if you call `sum_even_factorial(5)`

Comment: And if I understand your problem description right, how can the expected endresult be an odd number? I interpret "*sum of the factorials of the even numbers less than or equal to n*" as follows: Let `n = 10`, then your desired result is `10! + 8! + 6! + 4! + 2!`. Every factorial (except for `1!`) is an even number (because you have `... * 2 * 1` at the end). So how can the sum of even nubers be odd?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a logical error in the current code?

To begin with, function `sum_even_factorial` doesn't return a value in every execution flow:

```
if cond1:
    return val1
elif cond2:
    return val2
else: # this part is missing in your code
    return val3
```

In addition, note that when you call this function, you are not doing anything with the value that it returns:

```
sum_even_factorial(6)
```

Finally, although parts of your code are not visible in your question, I tend to guess that you cannot recursively compute the factorials of even numbers the way you did it, because the factorial of an even number `n` depends on the factorial of the odd number `n - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code needs a loop. I'd write it like so:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1;
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
def sum_even_factorial(n):
    current_sum = 0
    while n >= 0:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            current_sum += factorial(n)
        n -= 1
    return current_sum
        
print(sum_even_factorial(6))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return tuples from the function, you can do it with one single function. See the comments in the code on how it works ...

```py
def factorial_with_sum(n):
  if n < 2:
    return 1, 0  # first item of the tuple is the factorial, second item is the sum
  else:
    f, s = factorial_with_sum(n - 1) # calc factorial and sum for n - 1
    f = f * n # factorial = n * factorial (n - 1)
    if n % 2 == 0:
      s = s + f  # if n is even, add the current factorial to the sum
    
    return f, s
    
    
fact, sum = factorial_with_sum(6)
print(fact)
print(sum)
```

You can also do it iteratively with a simple for loop as follows

```py
def factorial_with_sum_iterative(n):
  s = 0 # initialize sum 
  f = 1 # and factorial
  
  for i in range(2, n + 1): # iterate from 2 to n
    f = f * i # calculate factorial for current i
    if i % 2 == 0:
      s = s + f # if current i is even, add it to sum

  return f, s
```